# Why do I get so many corrupt saves?

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-4, xbox-one

Almost every time I turn my XBox on and start up Fallout 4, I am unable to use the "Continue" option because the most recent save is corrupt.

I instead use the "Load" option. Here, I can see that the last save I manually performed is perfectly fine, and load it with no problem. However, there is an additional, corrupt save with the same time stamp immediately after it.

This doesn't happen *quite* every time, but often enough that I'm surprised when there's no corrupt save waiting for me to delete it.

I've tried a few things to solve this, including exiting to the game's main menu before turning the XBox off, going out to the guide before turning the XBox off, turning it off immediately after saving, and waiting a while after saving.

Why do I get all these corrupt saves? Do others have this problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: probly alt f4 related :p

Comment: I get these often. I always save and quick save, and exit to menu just to be safe.

Comment: Does the Xbox give you the ability to check saves without exiting the game? PS4 does not, but if you can, it might be possible to try a few scenarios and see when the corrupt file shows up.

Comment: @DangerZone I can look at the saves from the Load option on the start menu. I haven't noticed it showing up until after turning the box back on yet, but maybe.

Comment: @Ted Does that work?

Comment: @DCShannon. I don't know if 'works' is the right term...it just guarantees that I'll at least have a good save to load from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This no longer happens after recent patches.

Answer (score 0):

After performing a save, you must re-enter the pause menu and use the 'Exit' option. This will prevent saves from becoming corrupt.

Comment: This was one of the things I tried that I mentioned in the question: "including exiting to the game's main menu before turning the XBox off".